# MVC dynamic navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating an MVC application, but I want the navbar to be different for different type of users (for some users, some attributes should be hidden).

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Declaration System", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rules", "Rules", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Declare", "Declare", "Account")
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Set homework", "SetHomework", "Account")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("My marks", "MyMarks", "Account")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Classes", "Classes", "Account")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>© 2016 - Project by Yulia Buyanova and Maciej Miśkiewicz</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
<style>
    footer {

     position:fixed;
        bottom:15px;
  }


</style>
```

I store my user types in database, so I would like to check if currently logged person is of type X and then display correct navbar. And also a separatr navbar for not logged in. How do I do this?
Edit:
In normal conrollers I pass entities this way:

```
public ActionResult MyMarks()
        {
            ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities=new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
            return View(entities.Users.ToList());
        }
```

But how does it work for navbar?

Comment: You can't just use a simple `if` statement? For example `@if(userType == "Admin") { ... }`

Comment: @DavidG how do I pass all entities of my DB to this so that I can access the database and check for user type?

Comment: Why do you need to pass in all the entities? You only need to pass in the current user type.

Comment: @DavidG Exactly. But using @ HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name will not help. This only stores basic user data. More advanced data is stored in separate database (such as userType)

Comment: How would you get the user type in your controller? You can pass that in `ViewBag` for example. There's lots of ways to achieve this.

Comment: you need to query your user related table(s) (or a cache) using the basic info and get the data needed.

Comment: "type of users" == `Roles` (?) If so, while this link is "overkill" it does give you insight into how to use `Roles` [Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and SQL DB and deploy to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database) - you can skip the Azure parts and just focus on the Identity -> Roles section. Hth

Answer (score 2):

I would create a partial page and call it `_NavigationMenuPartial` and put this code in there:

```
@model NavigationMenuModel

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @if (this.Model.UserType == UserType.Admin) {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Home", "Index", "Home" )</li>
    }
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Rules", "Rules", "Home" )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Declare", "Declare", "Account" )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Set homework", "SetHomework", "Account" )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "My marks", "MyMarks", "Account" )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Classes", "Classes", "Account" )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Contact", "Home" )</li>
</ul>
```

From the controller pass the required information in a model to your view in your question. Then from that model you can pass only the part which your partial needs like this:

```
@Html.Partial( "_NavigationPartial", this.Model.NavigationMenuModel );
```

And here is the model but you can create it differently depending on your needs:

```
public class NavigationMenuModel {
   public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public enum UserType {
   Admin = 1,
   Enquiry = 2
}

public class MarksModel {
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }
   public NavigationMenuModel NavigationMenuModel { get; set; }
}
```

The controller can pass the model to your view in your question, like this:

```
public ActionResult MyMarks() {
   ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
   var model = new MarksModel();
   model.Users = entities.Users.ToList();
   model.NavigationMenuModel = new NavigationMenuModel { UserType = UserType.Admin };
   return View( model );
}
```

I have just passed the UserType.Admin as an example but you can pass whatever you need and and get the information form the database.

This is also a clean approach because everything related to your navigation is in a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Html.RenderAction then get the user however you intend to (cache it) then populate the partial view with a model from the db.